# Mercurial: No editor appears when merge conflicts are detected

Tags: mercurial

I wonder if anyone here has any experience with mercurial running on Ubuntu? I've been playing with it all morning and love everything I've seen so far.

The one problem I though is when I do a merge and conflicts are detected, it doesn't automatically bring the file up in the command line editor to allow me to resolve the conflicts. It just tells me there's a conflict, then it's up to me to open the editor and resolve it.

But this is strange as the docs show that the editor is automatically launched when there is a merge conflict. I know it's not a problem with the editor (nano) in general as it's works when I do a commit and have to add a comment.

Any ideas?

Chris

p.s I already tried the mercurial IRC channel, but silence....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to define your merge tool in ~/.hgrc:

```
[ui]
merge = vimdiff
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, that did the trick. The only problem now though is when it opens it in nano, it shows me three files. I've started another question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399897/mercurial-editor-doesnt-show-the-conflict-file-after-a-conflicted-merge

Answer (score 2):

What commands are you using, and what does your ~/.hgrc look like?  If you're using the fetch extension, it should be opening up a configured merge tool when a conflict is detected.

I detailed my full mercurial config [a while back in a blog post](http://naleid.com/blog/2008/11/25/my-mercurial-setup-plus-some-useful-shims-and-jigs/) where I use kdiff3 as my merge tool.

When doing an "hg fetch" or an "hg merge" (after a conflict is detected) it launches kdiff3 as you'd expect and lets me resolve the merge.