# Mercurial: Editor doesn't show the conflict file after a conflicted merge

Tags: mercurial

After having solved the problem of getting the editor to launch when there's a merge conflict - [Mercurial: No editor appears when merge conflicts are detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399606/mercurial-no-editor-appears-when-merge-conflicts-are-detected)

I now have another problem, the editor now launches but opens the files in the following order:

hello.c
hello.c~base.????
hello.c~other.????

But what I really want to see is the file that highlights the conflicts, which I expect should be the first one hello.c, but instead hello.c just shows the tip.

Any advice?

Regards,

Chris

Comment: What version of HG are you using , what is the output of 'hg heads' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what tool you're using for merges, but it sounds like it's doing a [3-way merge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(revision_control)#Three-way_merge).  The left pane is normally the common ancestor, the middle pane is the file you're merging in, and the right pane is your changes to the file.

I really like kdiff3 (free and open source) for merges and would recommend it if the tool that you're using isn't working for you.  It's in the mercurial documentation as the example merger that they use in many places.

Answer (score 2):

The first file ends up being the finished merge, so you need to make sure you manually copy in all changes from the other two files. Vimdiff works well for this as it highlights all differences between the three files. I'm not exactly sure how the three files are generated, but this process does seem to work for me.